The image component shrinks the width and height to fit everything into the screen width not making it scrollable
As the number of items increases, the image shrinks. How can I make sure the image's width and height are 500px and make sure it scrolls horizontally?
<ul className="flex flex-row w-screen overflow-x-auto">
  {data.map((item, index) => (
    <li key={index} className="w-500">
      <Image src={data.pic} width={500} height={500} alt="" />
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>


Add shrink-0 to the list items to prevent the items from shrinking. So something like:
<li className="w-500 shrink-0">


Heya! Sorry but how can I keep the ratio for all the pictures? Becasue, some pictures' height are different according to their ratios

If the heights are different and it's a horizontal scroll you probably want to remove the width property from the images. This will make the height 500 and the width auto scale.
